# Как проверить наличие файла в папке?

Tags: c#, uwp

Вот так я читаю инфу из файла:

```
var storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var file = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("test.txt");
var text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

А как проверить его наличие?

Comment: GetFileAttributes() можно использовать.

Comment: можно посмотреть в сторону [TryGetItemAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/windows.storage.storagefolder.trygetitemasync)

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо, ваш вариант больше подошел)

Comment: @Denisok, тогда добавь ответ с примером и пояснениями

Answer (score 3):

не лучше ли вот эта?

```
File.Exists (String)
```

Answer (score 1):

Получилось проверять по совету @Grundy используя TryGetItemAsync.
Сам код такой:

```
 var storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

 if (await storageFolder.TryGetItemAsync("test.txt") != null)
 {
     var file = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("test.txt");
     var text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

     if (text != "")
     {
        //Некоторый код
     }
 }
```